# How to select div which has particular element in class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to hide a div if its class has particular element.
Here is my code.

```
<div id="admin-menu" class="admin-menu-site-localhost admin-menu-processed admin-menu-position-fixed" style="position: fixed;">
    <div id="admin-menu-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

I need to select div with **menu** as element.
Because menu is appended to some other element. How can I filter those div's?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
jQuery("body")hasClass("div[class*='menu']");
```

Comment: <div id="admin-menu" class="admin-menu-site-localhost admin-menu-processed admin-menu-position-fixed" style="position: fixed;"><div id="admin-menu-wrapper"></div></div>

Comment: do you want to select any div with menu anywhere in the class like `admin-menu-site-localhost`? have you tried any js or jquery? Once you find a `div` with menu in it do you want to just hide it?

Comment: I have tried this
jQuery("body")hasClass("div[class*='menu']");
Yes, I need to select any div which has menu in class

Comment: again add the code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('[class*="menu"]').doSomething();
```

This will select any element that has `menu` in it's class list.

Answer (score 3):

This should return all `div` elements that contains `menu` in `className` property:

```
$('div[class*="menu"]')
```

or

```
jQuery('div[class*="menu"]')
```

Comment: I don't think he means the class ".menu". I think he means a class that contains the string "menu".